# Trying to add missing keywords to SD library 'keywords.txt' file

Tags: arduino

I searched for this issue, but I couldn't find anything about it. But, I noticed when I was writing a sketch that some keywords were not getting highlighted in the Arduino IDE.

Specifically, I was using the SD card library (based on [sdfatlib](http://code.google.com/p/sdfatlib/)), and I noticed that `isDirectory()`, `openNextFile()`, and a couple of other methods were not getting highlighted. So, I opened the `keywords.txt` file and added them in the appropriate section (`KEYWORDS2`). It didn't work. My questions are:

1. Why are they missing?
2. How do I add them (or should I add them) and get them to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might have been an oversight that these keywords are missing. You can add them to the `keywords.txt` file to get the highlighting.

In addition to that, you can also send a pull request to the official [Arduino GitHub repository](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino).

Comment: Found my problem! I had both Arduino 1.5 and 1.0.1 on my Mac - one in  my Applications folder and another on my dock.  I was editing the 1.0.1 version's keywords.txt file, but launching version 1.5.  Really careless mistake.  Please excuse my post and mark as closed.

Comment: I guess they were omitted because they were originally utility functions in `sdfatlib` and _not_ part of the Arduino SD wrapper.  This could be easily verified, but I don't have the time to trace them back. I know Arduino libraries do not normally include utility functions buried under their wrappers, so it is plausible.